# Question on order isomorphism of ordered sets $P,Q,R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to show that:

$$\langle P \rightarrow \langle Q \rightarrow R\rangle\rangle \cong \langle P \times  Q \rightarrow R\rangle$$

Comment: You can get real angle brackets with `\langle` ($\langle$) and `\rangle` ($\rangle$). What exactly do you mean by $\langle Q\to R\rangle$ in this context?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott some mapping from $Q \rightarrow R$

Comment: Some mapping, or the set of all mappings from $Q$ to $R$? Arbitrary mappings, or some particular kind?

Comment: arbitrary mapping